# Orfeo Tool Box installation-QGIS_2.18.10-Windows 10-64Bits

Tags: qgis, otb-applications

I installed QGIS 2.18.10 and then osgeo4w as you suggested it. I went to the Processing Provider options and entered the paths as you described it. But I do not still have OTB in my processing toolbox.

Can you help me? I don't have any other idea so far.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are really in the paths? Depending on the installation folder names may vary. It might help if QGIS is also from OSGEO4W setup.

Comment: Yes I checked many times the paths. I download QGIS 2.18 (64 bits) from the website download.qgis.org and I got OTB from OSGEO4W like it is explained there : How to configure Orfeo toolbox in QGIS 2.18 on Windows 7 32-Bit

I also uninstalled Qgis and all I got but maybe not all... And then I downloaded QGIS and OTB as I did before.

Comment: So you think I should get QGIS from Osgeo4W setup ?

Comment: Maybe you are in the simple mode. Are you in the advance mode (on the bottom of the processing toolbox)?

Comment: Yes I think so as it looks like that : https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/set_up.html but without the orfeo toolbox.

Comment: Screenshots of your Orfeo settings in QGIS and the processing toolbox? Maybe with them I can help you

Comment: Yes, take both QGIS and OTB from OSGEO4W. Maybe delete your `<username>\.qgis2\` folder before.

Comment: Ok I quite sure that I am on advance mode. So I uninstalled all I have linked to QGIS softaware. Now I am installing QGIS and OTB from OSGEO4W. Let you know what happens

Comment: Ok so now it is working !!! The solution was to download all from OSGEO4W. 
Thank you so much.